# How did "dis-" contribute to the meaning of "directus"?

Tags: etymology, prefix

Ayto doesn't expound how **addrictiāre* shifted to mean "direct something, such as a letter, to somebody".

> #### address [14]
>
> *Address* originally meant
> ‘straighten’. William Caxton, for example, here
> uses it for ‘stand up straight’: ‘The first day that
> he was washed and bathed he addressed
> him[self] right up in the basin’ *Golden Legend* 1483. This gives a clue to its ultimate source,
> Latin *dīrectum* ‘straight, direct’. The first two
> syllables of this seem gradually to have merged
> together to produce **drictum*, which with the
> addition of the prefix ad- was used to produce
> the verb **addrictiāre*. Of its descendants in
> modern Romance languages, Italian *addirizzare*
> most clearly reveals its source. Old French
> changed it fairly radically, to *adresser*, and it was
> this form which English borrowed. The central
> current sense of ‘where somebody lives’
> developed in the 17th and 18th centuries from
> the notion of directing something, such as a
> letter, to somebody.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 7 Right column.

Then I researched on [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=address), but the ***dis-* "apart"** baffles me! Firstly, the notion of "apart-ness" doesn't appear in *directus*. Second, how does the notion of apart-ness relate to the notion of straightness?

> [address | Search Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=address)
>
> early 14c., "to guide, aim, or direct,"
> from Old French *adrecier* "go straight toward; straighten, set right; point, direct" (13c.),
> from Vulgar Latin **addirectiare* "make straight" (source also of Spanish *aderezar*, Italian *addirizzare*),
> from *ad* "to" (see [ad-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ad-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) + **directiare* "make straight,"
> from Latin *directus* "straight, direct" past participle of *dirigere* "set straight,"
> from *dis-* "apart" (see [dis-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dis-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)) + *regere* "to direct, to guide, keep straight" (from PIE root [*reg-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*reg-) "move in a straight line"). Compare [dress (v.)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/dress).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Verb prefixes in Latin tend to have one of two functions. Sometimes they apply their own meaning to the verb, changing it in some significant way. And sometimes they just make the verb's meaning more intense and emphatic.

*Dīrigō*, imo, is the second type. The common meaning of "straighten" comes from "steer, guide" made more intense, rather than "steer, guide" plus "apart".

Some authors (L&S cite Brambach) disagree with me here; they say that *dīrigō* should only be used when things are being arranged all in different directions, because of the *dis-* prefix, and *d**ē**rigō* should be used for straightening things out. While this is a nice theory, it doesn't seem to line up with how the ancients actually used the words.

Comment: To be fair, the ancients might have confused de- and di-.